# cookies not getting expired in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

My cookies not getting expired,

I have `2pages` in `1page` I am `generating cookies` and on 2nd page I am trying to `expire cookies` and then redirecting it to a page where it gets generated but on back click of browser that page gets open

**.cs code** where it gets **generated** is in **1page.aspx**

```
HttpCookie editorid = new HttpCookie("editorid");
editorid.Value = Convert.ToString(rr1.First().editor_id);
Response.Cookies.Add(editorid);
Response.Redirect("2page.aspx");
```

**.cs code** where it gets "**redirected** and gets **expired**" is in **2page.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (Request.Cookies["editorid"] != null)
    {           
    }
     else
    {
        Response.Redirect("1page.aspx");
    }
}
 protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies["editorid"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1);
    Response.Redirect("1page.aspx");
}
```

on clicking **Linkbutton1** it gets redirected to `1page.aspx` but when I click back button it goes again back to `2page.aspx`

How should I expire cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description it seems that when the user clicks the back button the page is pulled from the back button cache which is pretty aggressive.

You can try to prevent this caching by [changing the `Cache-Control` header](http://blog.55minutes.com/2011/10/how-to-defeat-the-browser-back-button-cache/), in ASP.NET this could be done using the `OutputCache` directive at the top of your page.

```
<%@ OutputCache Location="None" VaryByParam="None" NoStore="true" Duration="1" %>
```

Comment: I want same as facebook, on logout it comes back to home page but on back button it does not pull back to that page nor showing any "document expire"...

Comment: you will then have to play around with global.asax

Comment: showing me error of duration should be positive, what should i make it?

Comment: i have never made use of global.asax so can you give demo of where should i place it in global.asax???

Comment: argaz the problem  is solved on putting this line on every page, but is there any trick to put in 1 page and it will apply in whole website, something like on master

Comment: that argaz the problem is solved my your help and also by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575819/output-cache-in-content-and-master-page

Answer (score 1):

Use sessions, that way you have more control, and can set the session to null if not in use anymore

Comment: But I want to use cookies

Comment: You can use cookies http://www.aboutcookies.org/default.aspx?page=5 for its purpose, but sessions for this you are trying to do

Comment: i am just making login credential of user and want them to login till it get logout, there is no requirement in security level, so i thought of using cookies and i am facing such problem